# EF Core relation in wrong direction

Tags: .net, entity-framework-core, one-to-many

I have products with allergies. However, when I try to model this in EF core, I can't get the one-to-many relationship to work. EF creates a new field, ProductId in Allergies and so only 1 product can have 1 allergy.

This is my code:

```
   public class Product
    {
        [Key]
        public int ProductId { get; set; }
        public string Name{ get; set; }
        public byte[] ImageData { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Allergie> Allergies { get; set; }
    }

  public class Allergy
    {
        [Key]
        public int AllergyId { get; set;  }
        public string Name{ get; set; }
    }
```

This seems to result in a One-To-One relation (with allergy ending up having a productId as well). How can I fix this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> This seems to result in a One-To-One relation (with allergy ending up having a productId as well). How can I fix this?

There is nothing to fix, because this is the correct implementation of one-to-many relationship for relational database.

Relationships always have two sides, and the multiplicity {from}-{to} depends on which side of the relationship you are looking from. So from `Product` sided it is one-to-many, but from `Allergy` side it is many-to-**one**. i.e. each `Allergy` has exactly **one** `Product`, which in database is represented with FK column in `Allergy` referencing the PK in `Product`.

Remember that database tables are flat, so the collection navigation property  `Product.Allergies` for a given `product` represents query like this

```
db.Allergies.Where(allergy => allergy.ProductId == product.Id)
```

This gives you many allergies per product since the `ProductId` in `Allergy` table is not unique. However the referenced column `Id` in `Product` table is unique, so the inverse reference navigation property `Allergy.Product` would represent for a given `allergy` query like this

```
db.Products.Single(product => product.Id == allergy.ProductId)
```

Reference: [Relationships](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships?tabs=fluent-api%2Cfluent-api-simple-key%2Csimple-key) in EF Core documentation.

---

With that being said, by not wanting FK in `Allergy` you probably a looking for [many-to-many](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships?tabs=fluent-api%2Cfluent-api-simple-key%2Csimple-key#many-to-many) relationship. This type of relationship requires additional "link" ("join") table, and in current EF Core release (3.1) it requires explicit entity class as explained in the documentation link:

> Many-to-many relationships without an entity class to represent the join table are not yet supported. However, you can represent a many-to-many relationship by including an entity class for the join table and mapping two separate one-to-many relationships.

The upcoming [EF Core 5.0 will add support for many-to-many relationships without explicitly mapping the join table](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-5.0/whatsnew#many-to-many), which will simplify creating such relationship, but until then you have to use the aforementioned approach.